# Testing email services in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, smtp, junit4

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have this email service that I want to test

```
@Service
public class MailClient {

    protected static final Logger looger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public MailClient(JavaMailSender mailSender, MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.mailContentBuilder = mailContentBuilder;
    }

    //TODO: in a properties
    public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setFrom("nunito@calzada.com");
            messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
            messageHelper.setSubject("Sample mail subject");
            String content = mailContentBuilder.build(message);
            messageHelper.setText(content, true);
        };
        try {
            if (looger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                looger.debug("sending email to " + recipient);
            }
            mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            looger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I've created this test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MailClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private MailClient mailClient;

    private GreenMail smtpServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        smtpServer = new GreenMail(new ServerSetup(25, null, "smtp"));
        smtpServer.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSendMail() throws Exception {
        //given
        String recipient = "nunito.calzada@gmail.com";
        String message = "Test message content";
        //when
        mailClient.prepareAndSend(recipient, message);
        //then
        String content = "<span>" + message + "</span>";
        assertReceivedMessageContains(content);
    }

    private void assertReceivedMessageContains(String expected) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        MimeMessage[] receivedMessages = smtpServer.getReceivedMessages();
        assertEquals(1, receivedMessages.length);
        String content = (String) receivedMessages[0].getContent();
        System.out.println(content);
        assertTrue(content.contains(expected));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        smtpServer.stop();
    }

}
```

But I got this error when running the test

```
Error creating bean with name 'com.tdk.service.MailClientTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mailClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tdk.service.MailClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Provide package structure for MailClient and Class having main() method through which we are running boot application.

Comment: As a side comment. Whenever possible, don't reinvent the wheel. Just have a look at **[Spring Boot Email Tools library](https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want to run an integration test without providing the beans!
Whenever you use `@Autowired`, you need to provide the beans required for the autowired component feed via context.
Therefore, you need to add a static class inside that test class with `@Configuration` annotation. Moreover, the test class also need to know which configuration must be used via `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. An example here:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MailClientTest.ContextConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MailClientTest {

    @Configuration
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties",
            properties ={"my.additiona.property=123"})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.tdk.service"})
    public static class ContextConfiguration {
      @Bean
      public JavaMailSender mailSender{
        return ... //create the instance here
      }

      @Bean     
      public  MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder() {
        return ... //create the instance here
      }
    }
}
```

---

Anyway, as I already pointed out in a comment, don't waste your time reinventing the wheel. There is already a library out of there that does all this stuff for you. I'm talking about [Spring Boot Email Tools](https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools).
I think it is worth to use that library and maybe contribute to the repository with new features instead of spending time for reimplementing email support with template engines.